# Finding cause of deadlock error from oracle trace file

Tags: oracle, deadlock, trace

I have been getting this "ora-00060 deadlock detected while waiting for resource" error often now in my application when multiple users are using the application. I have got the trace file from the oracle Admin, but need help in reading it. Below is bits of data from the trace file, which i hope would help in locating the cause.

```
*** 2013-06-25 09:37:35.324
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )

[Transaction Deadlock]

The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a deadlock due 
to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Deadlock graph:
                   ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-000151a2-00000000       210      72    SX   SSX      208      24    SX   SSX
TM-000151a2-00000000       208      24    SX   SSX      210      72    SX   SSX

session 72: DID 0001-00D2-000000C6  session 24: DID 0001-00D0-00000043 
session 24: DID 0001-00D0-00000043  session 72: DID 0001-00D2-000000C6 

Rows waited on:
 Session 72: no row
 Session 24: no row

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
Session 24:
 sid: 24 ser: 45245 audsid: 31660323 user: 90/USER
  flags: (0x45) USR/- flags_idl: (0x1) BSY/-/-/-/-/-
  flags2: (0x40009) -/-/INC
 pid: 208 O/S info: user: zgrid, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 2439
   image: oracle@xyz.local
 client details:
   O/S info: user: , term: , ospid: 1234
   machine: xyz.local program: 
 current SQL:
  delete from EMPLOYEE where EMP_ID=:1

 ----- End of information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

Information for THIS session:

 ----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=dyfg1wd8xa9qt) -----
 delete from EMPLOYEE where EMP_ID=:1
===================================================
```

I would appreciate if some one can tell me what the "Deadlock graph::" is saying. Also the rows waited on section says no rows.

I also read in some blogs that "sqltxt" section from the trace file can suggest the cause. Below is the query i see in that section.

```
 select /*+ all_rows */ count(1) from "USERS"."EMPLOYEE_SALARY" where EMPSAL_EMP_ID=:1
```

The employee_salary table has foreignkey constraint on EMPSAL_EMP_ID column.

The sql hint says "all_rows", so does it mean that this table gets table level lock when deleting records from employee table? i dont have an index on the foreign key column currently. Would adding an index on this column help?

Kindly post, in case any more information is need.

Thanks

Comment: Good topic on lock modes in Oracle: http://www.soug.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Newsletter/NL_public/NL_2013_1_Award_Article.pdf Seems like you missed index on `USERS.EMPLOYEE_SALARY.EMPSAL_EMP_ID` column and foreign constraint with `on delete cascade`.

Comment: it looks like you have two sessions trying to delete the same row.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all, `select` statement never lock anything in Oracle, just uses last available consistent version of data. It's not a case for `select ... for update` which locks data like `update` since Oracle 9i, but there are no `for update` clause in the query from question.

```
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-000151a2-00000000       210      72    SX   SSX      208      24    SX   SSX
```

Session #72 holds table-level lock (TM) with "Row Exclusive" type (SX) and want to acquire "Share Row Exclusive" (SSX) lock on same table. This session blocked by Session #24 which already holds table-level lock of a same type (SX) and waits while SSX lock would be available.

```
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-000151a2-00000000       208      24    SX   SSX      210      72    SX   SSX
```

This (second row) demonstrates exactly same situation, but in opposite direction: Session #24 waits for SSX lock become available, but blocked by Session #72 which already holds SX lock on same table.

So, Sessions #24 and Session #72 blocks each other: deadlock happens.

Both lock types (SX and SSX) are table-level locks.
To understand the situation I recommend to read [this article](http://www.soug.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Newsletter/NL_public/NL_2013_1_Award_Article.pdf) by Franck Pachot.

Below is citation from this article, which directly relevant to your situation(note that SSX and SRX abbreviations are equivalent):

> Referential integrity also acquires TM locks. For example, the common
>   issue with unindexed foreign keys leads to S locks on child table when
>   you issue a delete, or update on the key, on the parent table. This is
>   because without an index, Oracle has no single lower level resource to
>   lock in order to prevent a concurrent insert that can violate the
>   referential integrity.
>   When the foreign key columns are the leading
>   columns in a regular index, then the first index entry with the parent
>   value can be used as a single resource and locked with a row level TX
>   lock.
>   And what if referential integrity has an on delete cascade? In
>   addition to the S mode, there is the intention to update rows in the
>   child table, as with Row X (RX) mode. This is where the share row
>   exclusive (SRX) occurs: S+RX=SRX.

So, most probable variant is that Session #72 and Session #24 deletes some rows in `EMPLOYEE` table at same time,  and there are `on delete cascade` constraint for `EMPSAL_EMP_ID` in conjunction with absence of index on `EMPLOYEE_SALARY` table in which `EMPSAL_EMP_ID` column listed first.