# Error while trying to delete rows from table

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle-adf

I have a `DELETE` statement `delete from test where id = :a` in a package which is being called from Java. Each and every session trying to delete different set of rows from same table `test` but still I am getting error `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`.

Any help that what could have gone wrong here.

I can see the below in trace file but still I couldn't understand why exactly I am getting the deadlock.

```
*** 2018-08-28 06:55:08.128
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )
See Note 60.1 at My Oracle Support for Troubleshooting ORA-60 Errors
[Transaction Deadlock]

The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Deadlock graph:
                                          ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name                             process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TM-00049B33-00000000-00000000-00000000        288    2274    SX   SSX      320    2566    SX   SSX
TM-00049B46-00000000-00000000-00000000        320    2566    SX            142    1851    SX   SSX
TM-00049B33-00000000-00000000-00000000        142    1851    SX            288    2274    SX   SSX

session 2274: DID 0001-0120-00000406    session 2566: DID 0001-0140-00000019 
session 2566: DID 0001-0140-00000019    session 1851: DID 0001-008E-0001311B 
session 1851: DID 0001-008E-0001311B    session 2274: DID 0001-0120-00000406

Rows waited on:
  Session 2274: no row
  Session 2566: no row
  Session 1851: no row
```

is there any reason for not showing `ROWID` in the trace file?

Comment: Sounds like a design flaw in the packaged procedure.  If yu can't figure it out you'll need to post the code here, or at least a simplified version of the code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: i have added information from trace and you please check and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem often is caused by missing indices. If there is not arbitrary index for the where clause in your delete expression oracle will not only lock the records you're about to delete but will perform a table lock instead.
Make sure you have an index that contains most of the columns used in the where clause of your delete statement.

Answer (score 3):

A deadlock consists of two sessions locking each other, so that Oracle has to cancel one transaction to prevent them both from remaining locked indefinitely.

Let's say I delete item 1, and you delete item 2, and neither of us commits.

Now I try to delete item 2 - but I can't, because your uncommitted delete is locking the row, so my session waits in a blocked state, for you to either commit or roll back your delete.

Now you try to delete item 1. You can't, because my uncommitted delete is still locking that row. Now you are blocked by my session, but I am already blocked by you. (You need me to either commit or roll back, but I can't do either because I am blocked by you.) Both sessions will wait forever.

Oracle detects this situation and intervenes by cancelling and rolling back one of the transactions, raising ORA-00060 and writing a deadlock report to the database alert log.

Check the alert log for details, and review your application logic to stop this happening in future.

**Edit** - thanks for posting the trace details.

Session 2274 was waiting for 2566 (to get an SSX mode lock).
Session 2566 was waiting for 1851.
Session 1851 was waiting for 2274.

Some notes on lock modes: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/locks

SSX (share sub exclusive) is associated with `'Lock table in share row exclusive mode'`. Sometimes the locks and their associated modes aren't obvious, e.g. a direct path `insert` into a table, or a cascade delete via a foreign key (especially where the child key is unindexed) will lead to locks which you might not be expecting.

There may also be some clues in the answers to this question:  [Finding cause of deadlock error from oracle trace file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17358088/230471)

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation. However in my case I delete item 1, you delete item 2 and person X delete item 3 and we all there never tries to delete neither  item 1 or 2 or 3 so i should not be getting deadlock error. I have added trace and you please check and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, when you are trying to delete rows, another process seems to be accessing those rows at the same time. The first process locks those rows. This is known as a "race condition". 
It might be your package procedure which causes the problem or it might be something else (you will have to analyse your code).

Answer (score 0):

When any deadlock happens,
You can wait a few minutes and try to re-execute the statement(s) that were rolled back.

You can execute a ROLLBACK and re-execute all statements since the last COMMIT was executed.

I am not sure about the thing..but you can refer this website link http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00060_deadlock_detected_while_waiting_for_resource.htm...